# java native modules is undefined in react native (android)

Tags: java, android, react-native

I tried to add a java file into react native. The compile process is ok, while I can't get valid class from js file in react native. Sincerely asking for help! Thank you a million!

First, I added 2 files into android/app/src/main/java/com/awesomeproject/, named "MyToastModule.java" and "AnExampleReactPackage.java", the code are as follows:

```
//MyToastModule.java

package com.awesomeproject;
//package com.facebook.react.modules.toast;


import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import java.util.Map;

public class MyToastModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  private static final String DURATION_SHORT_KEY = "SHORT";
  private static final String DURATION_LONG_KEY = "LONG";

  public MyToastModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "MyToastAndroid";
  }

  @ReactMethod
 public void show(String message, int duration) {
   Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, duration).show();
     }
 }


//AnExampleReactPackage.java

package com.awesomeproject;
//package com.facebook.react.modules.toast;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class AnExampleReactPackage implements ReactPackage {

  @Override
  public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  @Override
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
                              ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
    modules.add(new MyToastModule(reactContext));

    return modules;
  }

}
```

Then I updated the code in MainActivity.java and MainApplication.java, the codes are as follows:

```
//MainActivity.java
package com.awesomeproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {


    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "AwesomeProject";
    }
}

//MainApplication.java
package com.awesomeproject;

import android.app.Application;

import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements     ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new AnExampleReactPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
   SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

  }
}
```

I used

```
    react-native run-android
```

to run the react native. The compile process is ok. (Is 'npm' command needed for native modules?)

And I quoted the class in react native like this:

```
var { NativeModules }=require('react-native');

console.warn('NativeModules.ToastAndroid:'+
NativeModules.ToastAndroid);//works ok, shows[object]

console.warn('NativeModules.MyToastAndroid:'+
NativeModules.MyToastAndroid);//not working, shows[undefined]
```

The funny thing is that the original native module "ToastAndroid" works ok, while the new one "MyToastAndroid" does not work.

The compile info are as follow, if it might helps:

```
Scanning 569 folders for symlinks in /Users/xxx/AwesomeProject/node_modules (25ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee101Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore101Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco101Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline101Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase101Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3101Library
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0434Library
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningDebug
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus_5X_API_23_new(AVD) - 6.0' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 16.659 secs
Running /Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on emulator-5554     (/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: did you figure it out?